# How do I re-size an icon

Tags: icons

I like this [remove](http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/12607/48/close_delete_error_exit_false_incorrect_remove_icon) icon (png format), but unfortunately it's bigger. The icon finder site doesn't seem to contain a smaller size, maybe the same icon of size 16x16 would be preferable. How do I re-size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just download that icon and resize manually, using [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/), for example?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows, this free software might be useful: http://www.getpaint.net/

Answer (score 1):

Just use Photoshop, or png2ico... http://www.winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/

In Photoshop, open the file, then go to 'file' >> 'save for web and devices' resize it then save.

Answer (score 1):

Try to resize it online by this link: http://resizr.lord-lance.com

Comment: looks like only jpg is supported, my files are in png

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, use MS-Paint. Click Ctrl-W , in stretch section, change to 50% horizontal and 50% vertical or any ratio that will suit your need.